# Can't switch compiler in QT Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, raspberry-pi

Using QT Creator 5.02 for Raspberry PI cross compilation, and it appears that QT creator will use the compiler from the mkspecs/qws/qmake.conf which I used to build the QT for my device. This appears to happen regardless of the compiler I have defined in my kit.

The problem is, I suspect a problem with that compiler, and would like to try a different one, but can't seem to find a way to do this.

I've gone so far as to delete ~/.config/QtProject directory (thus erasing my entire QT creator configuration) and starting from scratch.

There must be a way to force it to use the correct compiler.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've managed to install qt on the RPi and compile a Qt project, but haven't tried/succedded in compiling or the pi on a regular computer. How are you trying to compile for armv6 ? Does compiling on the RPi help ?